# Sort three numbers in array from least to greatest

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, for-loop, numbers

I have to create a function that takes 3 numbers. The function should return an array containing the numbers from least to greatest. So far I have this.I know it isn't correct but it's a start.I'm not using native functions as well. Can anyone give me some tips? Appreciate any help.

```
   function leastToGreatest (num) {
        var array = [];
        var num1 = 0;
        var num2 = 0;
        var num3 = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
           if(num[i] < num[i] && num[i] < num[i]) {
                  num[i] = num1;
                  array.push(num1);
           }
           else if(num[i] > num[i] && num[i] < num[i]) {
             num[i] = num2;
             array.push(num2);
           }
           else if(num[i] > num[i] && num[i] > num[i])
             num[i] = num3;
             array.push(num3);
           }
           return array;
     }
     leastToGreatest(2,1,3);
```

Comment: There's [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for this

Comment: You know that `num[i]` can not be any different than `num[i]`, don't you? ..It means that all of your conditions will result in false, and that in each loop you are pushing `num3` to array.

Comment: @Washington Guedes yeah, I know. It's kind of just pseudo code to have something written out

Comment: @padawan07. So, what's the real issue? Have you tried to code out your "pseudocode"?

Comment: If you are trying to code a sort function by yourself, you can easily search sort methods on the web, there are: bubblesort, quicksort, mergesort, and so on. I am downvoting your question because you didn't show any initial effort.

Comment: BTW, `leastToGreatest = (...nums) => nums.sort((x, y) => x - y);`

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I was trying to figure out a comparison method for three numbers. I don't know a way of calling it besides [i] so I used that for each number knowing it wasn't correct. I've been searching basic ways of doing it but I've only gotten abbreviated methods that use native functions. I'm new to JS.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using two `for` loops to solve this problem. For example,

```js
function sortArray(array) {
  var temp = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
      if (array[j] < array[i]) {
        temp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(sortArray([3,1,2]));
```

With this function, no matter what size the array is it will always sort it.

The reason your function is not working (as is stated by @WashingtonGuedes) is that you are comparing the same value each time. As they said, you will reach the last statement and receive two `false`'s, which causes you to test `false` for all three `if` statements. Your returned array, then, will be empty.

One suggestion is to not hard-code for three values, as you have done, but instead assume nothing and let the program do the hard work. As put in my code snippet, you can enter an array of any length and it will be sorted, not just where length is 3.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes the OP is obviously asking for a hand-written function, not a native function, as is stated in the question.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes But I agree about correcting OP, will edit post to reflect.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Ah, corrected. Your first comment on OP's question is wrong as well, as no `if` statements return true and therefore none get executed, leaving `array` to be empty, just as it started.

Comment: The last `else if` doesn't have curly braces `{}`

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Ah very true. Many mistakes in his code, as well as `num3` always being 0 since it is being assigned to `num[i]` instead of `num[i]` being assigned to `num3`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it is now currently does not work because you are comparing a number with itself, so it will always be equal (causing your sorting to do nothing). To get a working sort you could fix this or use [array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: Yeah, I know it's wrong. I stated it. It's just pseudo type code I wrote out. I'm new to JS. How would I be able to compare the numbers in the array without using a native function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fun little variation on this:

```js
var sortingFunction = function(){ 
  console.log([].slice.apply(arguments).sort(function(a, b) {  return a - b; })); 
}


sortingFunction(3,2,5,1);
```

You can pass in as many numbers as you want, not just three. If you want to limit it to three you can test it in the function:

```js
var sortingFunction = function(){ 
  var values = [].slice.apply(arguments);
  if(values.length === 3) {
    console.log(values.sort(function(a, b) {  return a - b; })); 
  }
  else
  {
    console.log('you didn\'t pass in three values');
  }
 }


sortingFunction(3,2,5,1);


sortingFunction(3,31,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an array with numbers arranged from least to greatest, you can use the sort() method with the following parameter:

```
array.sort(function(a,b){return(a-b)});
```

```js
var array = [12,7,18,1];
array.sort(function(a,b){return (a-b)});
console.log(array); //Array should be arranged from least to greatest
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just three items you want to sort, you can do it quite easily with three comparisons and swaps:

```
if (num[0] > num[1])
{
    // swap num[0] and num[1]
    temp = num[0]; num[0] = num[1]; num[1] = temp;
}
if (num[0] > num[2])
{
    // swap num[0] and num[2]
    temp = num[0]; num[0] = num[2]; num[2] = temp;
}

// at this point, num[0] contains the smallest of the three numbers

if (num[1] > num[2])
{
    // swap num[1] and num[2]
    temp = num[1]; num[1] = num[2]; num[1] = temp;
}

// your three items are sorted
```

This is easy to prove correct by hand. Write the numbers 1, 2, and 3 on small pieces of paper, lay them out in random order, and then perform those steps above. No matter what order you start with, this will sort those three items.

Understand, the above only works for three items. If you want a way to sort any number of items, then you'll want to use the built-in sorting method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sort = function ([x, y, z]) {
  var k = [x, y, z];
  k[0] = Math.min(x, y, z);

  if ((x < y && x > z) || (x < z && x > y)) {
    k[1] = x;
  }
  else if ((y < x && y > z) || (y < z && y > x)) {
    k[1] = y;
  }
  else {
    k[1] = z;
  }

  k[2] = Math.max(x, y, z);
  return k;
};
```